# Get windows proxy username/password

Tags: windows, proxy, credentials

I have an access to a preconfigured Windows XP 32-bit workstation.
It's under firewall and to get outside it uses http proxy server.
To get proxy settings I need host, port, username and password.

> http: // username : password @ server : port

I'm able to find the proxy url and port (from PAC - automatic config file), 
but I don't know how to get username/password. Is there a way to read it somehow? At least username? I might get the admin rights.

Do you know any tool that can help?

I only found these MS docs about some methods to get proxy config connection, but I don't know how to determinate what's the provided credentials:

[WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384096%28VS.85%29.aspx)

[WINHTTP_CURRENT_USER_IE_PROXY_CONFIG structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384250%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[WinHttpGetProxyForUrl function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384097%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I've also found this lib, but it's rather for parsing PAC:
http://code.google.com/p/pacparser/

Comment: I've found the other way to get the proper credentials, but I'm curious if it's possible to determinate it somehow using any tool/in programming way.

Comment: I've partially solved the problem by digging into windows registry:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/819961
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
"MigrateProxy"=dword:00000001
"ProxyEnable"=dword:00000001
"ProxyHttp1.1"=dword:00000000
"ProxyServer"="http://ProxyServername:80"
"ProxyOverride"="<local>"

Comment: how  can we find the proxy user name and password from the registry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating on Fernando Sanchez's answer and Robert's comment, you need to authenticate via [SSPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Support_Provider_Interface). In my case I've connected using NTLM using [this link](https://isc.sans.edu/forums/diary/curl+and+SSPI/25812/)

With [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) using ntlm :

```
curl.exe --proxy <proxy_name>:<proxy_port> --proxy-ntlm -U : https://www.google.com
```

Also to partially answer your question the `-U :` means from [curl man page](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) :

> If you use a Windows SSPI-enabled curl binary and do either Negotiate
>   or NTLM authentication then you can tell curl to select the user name
>   and password from your environment by specifying a single colon with
>   this option: "-U :".

You can get the proxy name and port from the windows registry (regedit). Quote from Robert's comment:

> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
>   Settings]

It can be present either in a manual way using `REG_SZ ProxyServer` or using an autoconfiguration script using `REG_SZ AutoConfigURL = https://<configuration_url>`

If the [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) command above fails with `Failure when receiving data from the peer` maybe you have a [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) release without NTLM, SSPI or OpenSSL. Try with the latest [curl release](https://curl.haxx.se/windows/)

Answer (score 4):

In windows you cannot get password.
To get connect throw a proxy you have to use SSPI, check libcurl, you can get a connected socket throw proxy, build it with enable-sspi and openssl.